# Sending Email via Spring boot "spring-boot-starter-mail"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails using spring boot, but am getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not yet implemented
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:89)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.SmartMimeMessage.<init>(SmartMimeMessage.java:52)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:325)
```

I have used this maven entry:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port= 25
spring.mail.username= test
spring.mail.password= test
```

And My code:

```
@Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

private void send() {
        MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
            helper.setTo("mymail@mail.co.uk");
            helper.setReplyTo("someone@localhost");
            helper.setFrom("someone@localhost");
            helper.setSubject("Lorem ipsum");
            helper.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [...]");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}
        javaMailSender.send(mail);
        //return helper;
    }
```

This appears to be a straight forward but don't what am I missing!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the [it.ozimov:spring-boot-email-core](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools) library, that hides all these implementations behind a single component called `EmailService` - well, I'm also developing the library :).

Your example would be:

```
@Autowired
public EmailService emailService;

public void sendEmail(){
   final Email email = DefaultEmail.builder()
        .from(new InternetAddress("mymail@mail.co.uk"))
        .replyTo(new InternetAddress("someone@localhost"))
        .to(Lists.newArrayList(new InternetAddress("someone@localhost")))
        .subject("Lorem ipsum")
        .body("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [...]")
        .encoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).build();

   emailService.send(email);
}
```

With the following `application.properties`:

```
spring.mail.host=your.smtp.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=test
spring.mail.password=test
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

It also supports some template engines, like *Freemarker*, *Mustache* and *Pebble*, while you can extend it to use more template engines. Moreover, it also supports email scheduling and prioritization (e.g. high priority for password recovery and low priority for newsletter.

There is an article on LinkedIn explaining how to use it. It is [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-scheduling-mime-emails-java-using-spring-boot-roberto-trunfio).

Comment: Very nice library, thank you! I need to set custom mail headers but can't seem to figure out how. Can that be done? I also posted a question about that topic here on SO.

Comment: @JimArcher which headers? When an `Email` object is sent it is converted into a j`avax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`. So far I see two headers set in the conversion: `Disposition-Notification-To` and  `Return-Receipt-To` which are set via the `Email` methods `getDepositionNotificationTo()` and `getReceiptTo()`, respectively. If you think it is worth to have additional headers, it could be a good idea to open an issue on GitHub on the project repository.

Comment: what is `your.smtp.com` ?

Comment: @SandeshaJ is an invented value. You have to put your SMTP  host, if you use SMTP. Just put your host there. Go on the website for more examples: https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools

Comment: This library is not in active support now. So I would suggest using spring-boot-starter-mail.

Answer (score 18):

You have a second version of `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` on the classpath in addition to the one that's pulled in via `spring-boot-starter-mail`. A common culprit is Geronimo's JavaMail spec jar. Whichever jar it is, you need to exclude it from your application's dependencies. If you're not sure where it's coming from, running your application with `-verbose:class` will tell you.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, the problem I can see it that if I run it by mvn spring-boot:run, I get the problem, whereas when I run using java -jar target/myJar.jar, it works fine. So, do you still think it may be down to the duplicate lib?

Comment: Yes. I suspect the ordering of the classpath is different between `mvn spring-boot:run` and `java -jar`. In the case where it works, the good version of the JavaMail classes will be on the classpath before the bad version and vice-versa in the case where it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();`
try to use `MimeMessagePreparator` & `MimeMessageHelper` instead

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    public MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder;

    public void sendEmail(Users user, VerificationToken verificationToken) throws Exception {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            String name = user.getFirstname();
            String vtoken = verificationToken.getVtoken();
            String url = "http://3.16.214.183:8888/home/".concat(String.valueOf(user.getUserid())).concat("/").concat(vtoken);
            String content = mailContentBuilder.build(name, url);
            helper.setTo(user.getEmail());
            helper.setSubject("AppName - Please Verify Your Email");
            helper.setText(content, true);
        };
        try {
            mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

It only seemed to require this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And I set properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=user.myapp@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```

FYI, the port you choose is not arbitrary - 465 was required for Gmail, for example. And you also needed to make changes to the sending Gmail account to get it to function properly. I did this a long time ago, but I'm positive I've seen that exception before. The lambda used in this example may be helpful in resolving that issue, but unfortunately I can't remember. Feel free to contact me if you need any clarification or would like to see more code of the example that I got working.